# How do I compare two C-string pointers?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write code to check whether two C-string variables are the same barring the difference of capitalization. Given the two input `books BOOKS`, the program should return 1, and with `Incorrect correct`, it should return 0. My code doesn't print it accurately.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int Judge_Char(const char* str1,const char* str2){
    char first[20],second[20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        first[i]=str1[i];
        second[i]=str2[i]; //assigned pointers to variable
    }                      //bc I didn't know other ways to compare

    int k=0,l=0;
    for(k=0;first[k]!='\0';k++);
    for(l=0;second[l]!='\0';l++); //got the length of the chars here


    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        first[i]=toupper(first[i]);
    }                             //i converted them to same case here
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        second[i]=toupper(second[i]);
    }

    for(int n=0;n<k;n++){
        for(int m=0;m<l;m++){
            if(first[n]==second[m]){
                return 1;           // i check whether they are same or not
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    char a[20],b[20];
    cin>>a>>b;
    int flag=Judge_Char(a,b);
    cout<<flag<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to normally compare c-strings?

Comment: Please call them c-strings.  `CString` is an unrelated C++ class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/using-cstring?view=vs-2019

Comment: You should not compare pointers.  You should compare the data that the pointers point to.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That's what I tried to do.

Answer (score 3):

Two things annoy me about C++:

1. There is no standard definition for *pi* (yet we have an extremely sophisticated random number library some of which *requires* a value for *pi* to be defined for it to be implementable).
2. There is no standard way of comparing two strings on a case-insensitive basis. A subset of the general case compare problem is defined by `isupper`, `islower`, `toupper`, and `tolower`. Yes indeed a full locale-aware case-insensitive compare is beyond the scope of the C++ standard library, but one could be conceived in simpler terms.

In Windows you use `::_stricmp` and `#include <string.h>`

In Unix you use `strcasecmp` and `#include <strcasecmp>`

---

An example where it's useful, even if it doesn't support the German SS, Norwegian Slashed o, &c. &c.

```
struct iLT
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const {
        return strcasecmp(lhs.c_str(), rhs.c_str()) < 0;
    }
};

typedef std::map<std::string, double, iLT> MapWithCaseInsensitiveKeys;
```

Comment: `toupper` and `tolower` are not actually sufficient (or indeed useful) for implementing a correct case insensitive comparison.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Go on, spill the beans?

Comment: C++20 adds [`std::pi_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants)

Comment: C++ is fundamentally incapable of doing `toupper` and `tolower` properly on Unicode.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Oh that has made my day!! I'm migrating! To hell with the economic cost and compiler bugs.

Comment: @Bathsheba The functions are not bijective. For instance, `correct_stricmp("straße", "STRASSE") == 0`, a fact which can’t be expressed in terms of case conversion.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Indeed, but quite often you want a "quick and dirty" case insensitive compare for the encoding that ships with the toolset.

Comment: Yes, for "quick and dirty" it's sufficient.  But if you're happy with quick and dirty, why are you programming in C++ in the first place?

Comment: @MarkRansom: A facetious answer to that is why are `::_stricmp` and `strcasecmp` there on the respective platforms.

Comment: There are plenty of people who would be perfectly happy if nothing existed beyond ASCII, and `_stricmp` and `strcasecmp` are made for them.  Heck I've used them myself.  But I don't try to pretend they're universal solutions.